# Padre giving an error message about a line that doesn't exist

Tags: perl, padre

I have this program that runs OK on Windows with "perl program.pl" in the command prompt or "perl program.pl file1.txt file2.txt".

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "there were ",scalar(@ARGV), " arguments passed to this program\n";
if ( scalar(@ARGV) > 1 )
{
    print "First Argument: $ARGV[0]\n";
    print "Second Argument: $ARGV[1]\n";
}


sub process_file($)
{
        my $filename = shift;
        print "will process file $filename\n";
        #open(INPUT_FILE,"<$filename") || die("could not open $filename");     
}
```

Even after exiting and coming back into Padre, I get this dialog box when I go to run it (it will still run OK if I click the Yes button):

> Warning X Line 31: Using a | char in open without a | at the beginning
>   or end is usually a typo. Do you want to continue?
>
> [YES] [NO]

Comment: You should not use prototypes (the `($)` part after your sub name) unless you know what they are for (which I am guessing you don't). Just use `sub process_file { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `or` instead of `||` with `open`.  As an aside, I have always been told that the three argument form of `open` is what should be used.  I do know that Perl doesn't always reference the line that has the problem.  Of course I am taking for granted that the commented out line is the line in question and you commented it out as a test?

Comment: I got the error initially with it not commented out, but I am still getting the error even with the line commented out. I am gonna try and completely restart the computer and see if I still get this.

Comment: Hold the presses. Before restarting I replaced || with or on the commented out line, and I don't get the error. When I put the || back instead of or in the - commented out line - I got the error again. And I don't get the error either way at the command line. Seems like that would mean it is an error in Padre. Anyway, I will consider that the solution - use "or" instead of "||". Thanks!